# random csv data jmeter maven setup

Tags: maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I would like to integrate blazemeter random CSV data plugin set into my jmeter maven project. I am new to both maven and jmeter 3.2, but I have got a project built.

However there is no information on how I can setup the random CSV data plugin and how it should be setup in the configuration of the POM file.

So far, I have added the dependencies for the plugin, but there is no documentation on configuration within the pom file.

Dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter</artifactId>
        <version>0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_components</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmeter-plugins-emulators</artifactId>
        <version>0.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.blazemeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmeter-plugins-random-csv-data-set</artifactId>
        <version>0.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Is there a way I can configure the plugin in the verify stage or do I configure the plugin by adding in the properties.user and set the values within the  in the pom file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how you should use dependencies in your JMeter Maven project, you should add any required [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) into `configuration/jmeterExtensions` section like:

```
<configuration>
    <jmeterExtensions>
        <artifact>com.blazemeter:jmeter-plugins-random-csv-data-set:0.6</artifact>
        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-emulators:0.4</artifact>
        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter:0.5</artifact>
    </jmeterExtensions>
    <downloadExtensionDependencies>false</downloadExtensionDependencies>
</configuration>
```

Full `pom.xml` just in case:

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>mvn-jmeter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>maven-jmeter-demo</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jmeterExtensions>
                        <artifact>com.blazemeter:jmeter-plugins-random-csv-data-set:0.6</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-emulators:0.4</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter:0.5</artifact>
                    </jmeterExtensions>
                    <downloadExtensionDependencies>false</downloadExtensionDependencies>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

More information:

- [Adding jar's to the /lib/ext directory](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-additional-libraries-to-the-classpath#adding-jars-to-the-libext-directory)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)